# php cutting multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Anyone can help me with a function or point me into the direction on cutting a multidimensional array?

Here is what I need:

```
$array[x][y][b][q][o][p];
$array[b][c][f][q][l][v];

$newArray = cut_array_depth($array, 2);

// Would return a new array with a maximum dimension of 2 elements
// all others would be left out
$newArray[][];
```

Thanks,

Comment: just out of curiosity how is this useful?

Comment: if $array[x][y][b][q][o][p] = 5 and $array[b][c][f][q][l][v]=3, What would your function exactly return?

Comment: @Guilhem Hoffmann , if sliced by 2, would return an multidimensional array with a maximum of 2 dimensions $array[][], both, $array[x][y] and $array[b][c] elements would be on that array, but any other child array would be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write yourself the solution (even if I don't really understand the 'cutting' logic)

```
<?php
function cut_array_depth($array, $depth, $currDepth = 0){
    if($currDepth > $dept){
        return null;  
    }
   $returnArray = array();
   foreach( $array as $key => $value ){        
      if( is_array( $value ) ){              
          $returnArray[$key] = cut_array_depth($value, $depth , $currDepth +1);
      } else {
          $returnArray[$key] = $value;
   }
   return $returnArray;

}
?>
```